# gcc 8.2: error: invalid 'asm': invalid address mode

Tags: gcc, arm64

The following statement is taken from iPXE. It compiles fine with gcc 7.3 but fails with gcc 8.2 on the aarch64 architecture. Here I get an error

```
error: invalid 'asm': invalid address mode
```

The macro argument einfo is a list of 5 parameters.

```
#define __einfo_error( einfo ) ( {          
    __asm__ ( ".section \".einfo\", \"\", " PROGBITS_OPS "\n\t"     \
              ".align 8\n\t"                                        \
              "\n1:\n\t"                                            \
              ".long ( 4f - 1b )\n\t"                               \
              ".long %a0\n\t"                                       \
              ".long ( 2f - 1b )\n\t"                               \
              ".long ( 3f - 1b )\n\t"                               \
              ".long %a1\n\t"                                       \
              "\n2:\t.asciz \"" __einfo_desc ( einfo ) "\"\n\t"     \
              "\n3:\t.asciz \"" __FILE__ "\"\n\t"                   \
              ".align 8\n\t"                                        \
              "\n4:\n\t"                                            \
              ".previous\n\t" : :                                   \
              "i" ( __einfo_errno ( einfo ) ),                      \
              "i" ( __LINE__ ) );                                   \
```

- From where does

  ```
  .long %a0
  ```

  take its value?
- What is the "i" statement doing?
- Where is a reference for this syntax? - Has it changed with gcc 8.2?

Comment: What you are looking at is gcc's [extended asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).  As the docs describe, items after the colons are *output : input* items (so you have 2 inputs).  As described in the [simple constraints](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Simple-Constraints.html) section, "i" means *An immediate integer operand (one with constant value)*.  And gcc's inline asm syntax hasn't changed (much) for years.

Comment: I do note that this code uses an undocumented modifier (`%a0` vs `%0`).  Since *none* of the modifiers for aarch64 are documented, this code is depending on an unsupported feature.  What's more, looking at the [code](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/config/aarch64/aarch64.c?view=co&content-type=text%2Fplain) (search for `manner`), I don't see any definition or implementation for 'a'.  Perhaps the 'change' was that 8.2 rejects unknown modifiers?

Comment: I have the same issue so I gave it a try, and the code **does** compile when `%a0` and `%a1` are replaced with `%0` and `%1`, respectively. But I don't really know what I'm doing by changing these format strings.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. For x86 we need %a0, %a1. For ARM64 it is not allowed.